# Chmod -r issues

Tags: permissions, chmod

This may be a silly question, however I wish for the purposes of testing to change a folders permissions to incl all subdirectories. However I type

```
sudo chmod -r 755 bwjam/
```

and

```
 chmod -r 755 bwjam/
```

respectively to no avail. The returning result is

```
chmod: cannot access '755': No such file or directory
```

If I don't inlcude the -r flag it works just fine, I assume I'm getting something wrong, but I can't find the what I'm doing wrong with google. Care to shed some light?

Comment: Did you try with `-R`, instead of `-r`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chmod` uses `-R` for recursion, not `-r`. (This is true for `chown` and brothers too that deal with standard permissions, and come with GNU `coreutils`).

**Because:** if you use `-r`, then it will be taken as a symbolic permission representation of the Read permission bit, and necessarily means **remove (`-`) the Read (`r`) bit from whatever follows**, and then the octal bits `755` (and whatever follows) will be taken as file name(s).

You might have mixed these options with the `cp`'s (also from `coreutils` by the way) `-r`/`-R`, in `cp` both means the same thing, recursion.

---

In a nutshell, you need:

```
chmod -R 755 bwjam/
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be `chmod -R 755 bwjam/` for recursive. `-r` is not a valid option for recursive with `chmod`.

Answer (score 3):

The correct option letter for recursive mode changes is an upper case `R`

```
-R, --recursive
       change files and directories recursively
```

When you write

```
chmod -r 755 bwjam/
```

the command is interpreting `-r` as an instruction to *remove read permission from* the files `755` and `bwjam/`